# Escaping a literal asterisk as part of a command

Tags: bash

Sample bash script

```
QRY="select * from mysql"
CMD="mysql -e \"$QRY\""
`$CMD`
```

I get errors because the * is getting evaluated as a glob (enumerating) files in my CWD.

I Have seen other posts that talk about quoting the "$CMD" reference for purposes of echo output, but in this case

`"$CMD"`

complains the whole literal string as a command.

If I

```
echo "$CMD"
```

And then copy/paste it to the command line, things seems to work.

Comment: How about `\*` or wrap your query in single quotes.

Comment: Then it seemed to be coming as a literal \* as part of the CMD, not escaping as desired

Comment: @cerebriform: No quoting variation can help in this scenario. The issue is that you can't embed an (escaped) quoted string in another string and have simple variable expansion (`$CMD`) recognize the embedded string as a such; see my answer for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use:

```
qry='select * from db'
mysql -e "$qry"
```

This will not subject to `*` expansion by shell.

If you want to store `mysql` command line also then use BASH arrays:

```
cmd=(mysql -e "$qry")
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682071/45375) has the right solution.
This answer provides background information.

As for why your approach didn't work:

`"$CMD"` doesn't work, because bash sees the entire value as a *single* token that it interprets as a *command name*, which obviously fails.

---

```
`$CMD`
```

i.e., enclosing `$CMD` in backticks, is pointless in this case (and will have unintended side effects if the command produces stdout output<sup>[1]</sup>); using just:

```
$CMD
```

yields the same - broken - result (only more efficiently - by enclosing in backticks, you needlessly create a subshell; use backticks - or, better, `$(...)` only when embedding one command in *another* - see [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)).

---

`$CMD` doesn't work,

- because unquoted use of `*` subjects it to pathname expansion (globbing) - among other shell expansions.
- `\`-escaping glob chars. in the string causes the `\` to be *preserved* when the string is executed.

While it may *seem* that you've enclosed the `*` in double quotes by placing it (indirectly) between *escaped* double quotes (`\"$QRY\"`) inside a double-quoted string, the **shell does *not* see what's between these escaped double quotes as a single, double-quoted string**.

Instead, these double quotes become *literal* parts of the tokens they abut, and the shell still performs *word splitting* (parsing into separate arguments by whitespace) on the string, and expansions such as globbing on the resulting tokens.

If we assume for a moment that globbing is turned off (via `set -f`), here is the breakdown of the arguments passed to `mysql` when the shell evaluates (unquoted) `$CMD`:

- `-e      # $1` - all remaining arguments are the unintentionally split SQL command.
- `"select # $2` - note that `"` has become a literal part of the argument
- `*       # $3`
- `from    # $4`
- `mysql"  # $5` - note that `"` has become a literal part of the argument

---

The only way to get your solution to work with the existing, single string variable is to use `eval` as follows:

```
eval "$CMD"
```

That way, the embedded escaped double-quoted string is properly parsed as a single, double-quoted string (to which no globbing is applied), which (after quote removal) is passed as a single argument to `mysql`.

However, **`eval` is generally to be avoided** due to its security implications (if you don't (fully) control the string's content, arbitrary commands could be executed).

Again, refer to [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682071/45375) for the proper solution.

---

<sup>[1] A note re using `` `$CMD` `` as a command by itself:

It causes bash to execute *stdout output from `$CMD`* as *another* command, which is rarely the intent, and will typically result in a broken command or, worse, a command with unintended effects.

Try running `` `echo ha` `` (*with* the backticks - same as: `$(echo ha)`); you'll get `-bash: ha: command not found`, because bash tries to execute the command's output - `ha` - as a command, which fails.</sup>

Comment: Is eval any less secure than backticks?

Comment: @atxdba: Yes, because eval allows for injection of commands into strings that mere variable expansion would not execute. Consider `v='date; echo injected command'`. `$v` would fail (it treats all tokens as a _single_ command), whereas wheras `eval "$v"` would parse the string as a command line and execute the injected command. It is acceptable to use `eval` if you fully control creation of the string that you pass to it, but using `eval` is a dangerous habit to form. In most cases, and certainly in the case at hand, a safe alternative exists.